# Php no conecta con mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, servidor

Tengo un nuevo servidor que tiene recién instalado `apache2.4`, `php-5.3.29` y `mysql 5.0.08` (necesito esas versiones).

He migrado unos proyectos a este nuevo y ninguno de ellos conecta con la base de datos. En el otro servidor funcionan correctamente. Las credenciales de la `bbdd` son correctas en cada uno de sus archivos de configuración (wordpress y drupal). Con `mysql` accedo con cada una de las credenciales y puedo ver y hacer consultas sin problema. `Apache`, `Php` y `mysql` están corriendo pero cuando accedo a "midominio.com" me aparece:

> "Error al establecer una conexión con la base de datos".

No sé que puede pasar..

```
define('DB_NAME', 'pruebasw'); // Nombre de la base de datos
define('DB_USER', 'pruebasw'); // Usuario de la base de datos
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'passwd'); // Contraseña de la base de datos
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Host de la base de datos
```

Comment: Hola Marianito y bienvenido a esta gran plataforma. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta con el código que tienes? Aunque lo más probable es que necesites usar mysqli o pdo.

Comment: Esta usando mysqli, pero nada..

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la base de datos donde se instaló Wordpress o a otra base de datos? El Wordpress sí funciona o tampoco?

Comment: La base de datos del proyecto u otro proyecto cualquiera. Wordpress sin funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Marianito,
Revisa tu conexion con ese ejemplo:

```
<?php
$dbname ="db_prueba";
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","",$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Change database to "mi_base_de_datos"
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);
echo 'conexion exitosa';
?>
```

Saludos.

Comment: en el archivo wp-config tengo lo editado en la pregunta

Comment: Usar root y sin contraseña para entrar a una base de datos es una mala idea bajo mi punto de vista.

Comment: Probé y tampoco llega... sigue apareciendo el mensaje: "Error al establecer una conexión con la base de datos"

Comment: Si Pedro, usar root es una mala idea. Pero, es solo un ejemplo, estoy de acuerdo..